# TypeError: Cannot convert a MPS Tensor to float64 dtype as the MPS framework doesn't support float64. Please use float32 instead

Tags: macos, pytorch

I am trying to load a pre-trained weight to mps GPU device of Apple M2.
This is my code`

```
sp_nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')  # 英文预料词库, sm/md/lg, 分词/词意标注



#启动MPS
#Run MPS
device = torch.device("mps" if torch.backends.mps.is_available() else "cpu")
mtl.to(device)


# 训练模式
mtl.train()
for e in range(epoches):

    # 记录损失函数
    loss_rec = []

    # 将抑郁症以及情绪分类的训练集，同时输入到模型中进行训练
    for idx, (b_dep, b_emo) in enumerate(zip(dep_train_loader, emo_train_loader)):  # (index, (dep_data, emo_data))
        # x - batch size, sequence len
        dep_x = b_dep[0].to('mps')
        dep_y = b_dep[1].to('mps')

        emo_x = b_emo[0].to('mps')
        emo_y = b_emo[1].to('mps')

        y_d, y_e = mtl(dep_x, emo_x)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # 计算抑郁症检测任务的损失函数，以及情绪分类任务的损失函数
        dep_loss = loss_(y_d, dep_y)
        emo_loss = loss_(y_e, emo_y)

        loss = dep_loss + 0.001 * emo_loss

        loss_rec.append(loss.cpu().item())

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

and this is the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xq/PycharmProjects/Paper/model.py", line 247, in <module>
    mtl.to(device)
  File "/Users/xq/PycharmProjects/Paper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1145, in to
    return self._apply(convert)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xq/PycharmProjects/Paper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 797, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/Users/xq/PycharmProjects/Paper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 820, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
                    ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xq/PycharmProjects/Paper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1143, in convert
    return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Cannot convert a MPS Tensor to float64 dtype as the MPS framework doesn't support float64. Please use float32 instead.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am a beginner at pytorch, and see no option to cast it as float32 while loading, as suggested by the exception. How to make this work?

My dumb workaround will be to load it into CPU, make it float32, and then load to mps device. But not sure how to do it, or will it even work.